# Dynamic in keyword contents in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to search a database the condition is:

`select * from table where colnam in ('1','2','3','4','5'//dynamically retrieves);`

So if any of the fields are not available, I get the query like this, for example if only two fields are present:

`select * from table where colnam in ('1','2','','','');`

but I want the query like

`select * from table where colnam('1','2');`

I don't want the extra quotation marks and comma.

```
$qry="select * from table where colnam in ('$int1','$int2','$int3','$int4','$int5')";

echo $qry;
```

returns

```
select * from table where colnam in ('1','2','','','');
```

if `$int3`, `$int4`, `$int5` are not present

Comment: Show us how you retrieve value !!

Comment: from where `//dynamically retrieves` comes?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: hello friends I just edited my question.

Comment: where do the $int s come from

Comment: $int s I get it from the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add non empty values into an array and `implode` it with `,` and use it in `IN()`

```
$vals = array();
for($i=1;$i<=5;++$i){
  if(isset(${"int".$i})) {
    $x = ${"int".$i};
    if(!empty($x))
        array_push($vals,"'".${"int".$i}."'");
  }
}

$ins = implode(",",$vals);

echo $qry="select * from table where colnam in ($ins)";
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/UmPkTaxu)

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

```
$val = "";
foreach ($values as $value) {


                 if($val == ''){
                     $val .= $value;
                 }
                 else{
                     $val .= ','.$value;
                 }
```

}

here $values contains dynamic column values('1','2','3','4','5').

and then use $val variable as a condition.

i hope this code help you..